# Variables added to page is not accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4.0 with Firefox 26.0 and Chromium 32.0.
I am opening a new page using on button click event:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', 'newPage', {
  reload: true,
  type  : "post",
  data  : {data: data}
});
```

I am also adding in newPage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsonCft = [[0,7,7],["24","7","30"]];
</script>
```

but I am not able to access jsonCft in Firefox 26.0 whereas I can access the variable in Chromium.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you will need to add a bit more code up here so we can understand where/when calls are happening.

Comment: remove the `var` and change it to `window.jsonCft = [[0,7,7],["24","7","30"]];`  It shouldn't be a scoping issue, but that will resolve it if it is.

Comment: @Arher window.jsonCft works for both. Thanks. But while working I figured out that the jsonCft is not available on first page load. I have to refresh the page to access jsonCft in the Console or the js files.